# Проблема с установкой phalcone

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, phalcon

Делаю так:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-dev libpcre3-dev gcc make php5-mysql git-core autoconf

/home/phalcon# git clone --depth=1 git://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon.git

/home/phalcon# cd cphalcon/build

/home/phalcon/cphalcon/build# sudo ./install
```

Ответы:

```
Build complete.
Don't forget to run 'make test'.

Installing shared extensions:     /usr/lib/php5/20121212/
Installing header files:          /usr/include/php5/
```

Далее

```
echo 'extension=phalcon.so' | sudo tee -a /etc/php5/mods-available/phalcon.ini
cd /etc/php5/mods-available
sudo php5enmod phalcon
/etc/init.d/php5-fpm restart
sudo service nginx restart
```

Но в результате пусто 
http://smartcook.info/resource/

Еще пробовал вот так:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:phalcon/stable

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install php5-phalcon
```

В общем топорно решил вопрос снес все поставил заново строкой

```
sudo apt-get install php5-cli php5-common php5-mysql php5-fpm php-pear php5-phalcon
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно что ваша проблема заключается в установке приоритета php экстеншена. Попробуйте в папке `/etc/php5/fpm/conf.d` создать файл `21-phalcon.ini` в котором определить расширение для `phalcon`.

При вызове `php -m` секция `phalcon` должна отображаться в списке `[PHP Modules]`.

P.s.  https://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/1851/phalcon-extension-not-loaded

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo ln -s -T /etc/php5/mods-available/phalcon.ini /etc/php5/conf.d/20-phalcon.ini
/etc/init.d/php5-fpm restart    
sudo service nginx restart
```

Comment: ссылка там вроде есть, но я все равно попробовал 
root@8220:/etc/php5/mods-available# sudo ln -s -T /etc/php5/mods-available/mods-available/phalcon.ini /etc/php5/conf.d/20-phalcon.ini
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/etc/php5/conf.d/20-phalcon.ini': No such file or directory

Comment: Вот http://prntscr.com/8drbuo

Comment: Я исправил, я дважды написал mods-available, попробуйте еще раз

Comment: root@8220:/etc/php5/mods-available# sudo ln -s -T /etc/php5/mods-available/phalcon.ini /etc/php5/conf.d/20-phalcon.ini
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/etc/php5/conf.d/20-phalcon.ini': No such file or directory

Comment: sudo ln -s -T /etc/php5/mods-available/phalcon.ini /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/20-phalcon.ini
/etc/init.d/php5-fpm restart    
sudo service nginx restart